# Unity: AdMob & UMP: Didn't find class "com.google.android.ump.UserMessagingPlatform"

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to implement Google AdMob's UMP for GDPR, etc. compliance.

When deploying on a device, shortly after this line runs:

```
ConsentInformation.Update(request, OnConsentInfoUpdated);
```

The following exception fires and the game stops:

```
16054 16140 Error Unity Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.google.android.ump.UserMessagingPlatform" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", 
zip file "/data/app/com.packagename-rCIR4M7S0arj_qYzQW_MZg==/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename-rCIR4M7S0arj_qYzQW_MZg==/lib/arm64, /data/a
```

I tried making some changes to the Proguard, like adding

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.** { <fields>; }
```

and

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

But they don't seem to help.

There are no issues when running this in Unity's editor.
I'm running Unity 2021.3.9f1 with AdMob SDK v11.0.0.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem on my android / unity game.

I could solve this problem by adding this line to my *proguard-user.txt* file.

```
-keep public class com.google.android.ump.**{
   public *;
}
```

So my *proguard-user.txt* looks like this.

```
-keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.ump.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate
```

Also, I checked the **Minify R8, Release and Debug** checkboxes under "Publishing Settings" -> "Minifiy"

I hope that works for you!

Comment: Yes! This worked. They really should have specified this in the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One other option to solve this issue is turn off Minify.

You only need to edit the proguard-user.txt for this issue in case you are using Minify.

Of course pros/cons is depend on you to consider.

[image]